# Use of java.math.MathContext

Tags: java, math, bigdecimal, mathcontext

Recently I tried understanding the use of **java.math.MathContext** but failed to understand properly. Is it used for rounding in `java.math.BigDecimal`. If yes why does not it round the decimal digits but even mantissa part.

From API docs, I came to know that it follows the standard specified in `ANSI X3.274-1996` and `ANSI X3.274-1996/AM 1-2000` specifications but I did not get them to read online.

Please let me know if you have any idea on this.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

@jatan

> Thanks for you answer. It makes sense. Can you please explain me MathContext in the context of BigDecimal#round method.

There's nothing special about `BigDecimal.round()` *vs.* any other `BigDecimal` method.  In all cases, the `MathContext` specifies the number of significant digits and the rounding technique.  Basically, there are two parts of every [`MathContext`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html).  There's a precision, and there's also a [`RoundingMode`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html).

The precision again specifies the number of significant digits.  So if you specify `123` as a number, and ask for 2 significant digits, you're going to get `120`.  It might be clearer if you think in terms of scientific notation.

`123` would be `1.23e2` in scientific notation.  If you only keep 2 significant digits, then you get `1.2e2`, or `120`.  By reducing the number of significant digits, we reduce the precision with which we can specify a number.

The `RoundingMode` part specifies how we should handle the loss of precision.  To reuse the example, if you use `123` as the number, and ask for 2 significant digits, you've reduced your precision.  With a `RoundingMode` of `HALF_UP` (the default mode), `123` will become `120`.  With a `RoundingMode` of `CEILING`, you'll get `130`.

For example:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("123.4",
                   new MathContext(4,RoundingMode.HALF_UP)));
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("123.4",
                   new MathContext(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP)));
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("123.4",
                   new MathContext(2,RoundingMode.CEILING)));
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("123.4",
                   new MathContext(1,RoundingMode.CEILING)));
```

Outputs:

```
123.4
1.2E+2
1.3E+2
2E+2
```

You can see that both the precision and the rounding mode affect the output.

Comment: Is there a way to format `123.4` using 2 significant figures result in a string like `120`? That's 2 significant figures (as is `1.2E2`) because trailing zeros aren't conventionally included in retrieval of significant figures unless there's a trailing decimal. And for my purposes, if the number to be formatted was `103.4`, I don't care that you can't tell there's 2 sig figs in the resulting `100` number. I just want simpler/cleaner viewing of numbers.

Answer (score 83):

For rounding just the fractional part of a BigDecimal, check out the `BigDecimal.setScale(int newScale, int roundingMode)` method.

E.g. to change a number with three digits after the decimal point to one with two digits, and rounding up:

```
BigDecimal original = new BigDecimal("1.235");
BigDecimal scaled = original.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

The result of this is a BigDecimal with the value 1.24 (because of the rounding up rule)

Comment: This is the answer people want, in working with fixed-decimal numbers & keeping a fixed number of decimal places. Don't know why Sun bungled a floating-point style 'precision' in here, but that's what MathContext is.

Comment: This even works to round a BigDecimal without any fractional part: `original.setScale(0,  RoundingMode.HALF_UP);`

Comment: @Derrick, that is not accurate. `public BigDecimal setScale(int newScale, int roundingMode)` was deprecated. But the version @Tobias mentions, `public BigDecimal setScale(int newScale, RoundingMode roundingMode)` is still valid.

Answer (score 20):

I would add here, a few examples. I haven't found them in previous answers, but I find them useful for those who maybe mislead **significant digits** with number of **decimal places**. Let's assume, we have such context:

```
MathContext MATH_CTX = new MathContext(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

For this code:

```
BigDecimal d1 = new BigDecimal(1234.4, MATH_CTX);
System.out.println(d1);
```

it's perfectly clear, that your result is `1.23E+3` as guys said above. First significant digits are 123...

But what in this case:

```
BigDecimal d2 = new BigDecimal(0.000000454770054, MATH_CTX);
System.out.println(d2);
```

your number **will not be rounded to 3 places after comma** - for someone it can be not intuitive and worth to emphasize. Instead it will be rounded to the **first 3 significant digits**, which in this case are "4 5 4". So above code results in `4.55E-7` and not in `0.000` as someone could expect.

Similar examples:

```
BigDecimal d3 = new BigDecimal(0.001000045477, MATH_CTX);
 System.out.println(d3);  // 0.00100

BigDecimal d4 = new BigDecimal(0.200000477, MATH_CTX);
 System.out.println(d4);   // 0.200

BigDecimal d5 = new BigDecimal(0.000000004, MATH_CTX);
    System.out.println(d5); //4.00E-9
```

I hope this obvious, but relevant example would be helpful...

Answer (score 6):

If I'm understanding you correctly, it sounds like you're expecting the MathContext to control how many digits should be kept after the decimal point.  That's not what it's for.  It specifies how many digits to keep, *total*.  So if you specify that you want 3 significant digits, that's all you're going to get.

For example, this:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("1234567890.123456789",
                   new MathContext(20)));

System.out.println(new BigDecimal("1234567890.123456789",
                   new MathContext(10)));

System.out.println(new BigDecimal("1234567890.123456789",
                   new MathContext(5)));
```

will output:

```
1234567890.123456789
1234567890
1.2346E+9
```

Comment: Thank you. How would I choose how many digits to keep after the decimal?

Comment: That's not really a question for BigDecimal.  With BigDecimal, you should instead be specifying the number of significant digits.  How many digits after the decimal point should be determined when formatting for display.  You can control that with String.format() or DecimalFormat.format().

Comment: @Drew I think you can use [BigDecimal.setScale](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/math/BigDecimal.java#BigDecimal.setScale%28int%2Cjava.math.RoundingMode%29) method for it. The first parameter(scale) specifies how many numbers you want to keep after the decimal point, and the second parameter(roundingMode) specifies the rounding behavior you want.

Comment: @Drew [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4194330/689991) is an answer that explains it in more details.

Answer (score 5):

It's not for fun. Actually I found some online example, which stated the use of `MathContext` to round the amounts/numbers stored in BigDecimal.

For example,

If `MathContext` is configured to have `precision = 2` and `rounding mode = ROUND_HALF_EVEN`

`BigDecimal Number = 0.5294`, is *rounded* to **0.53**

So I thought it is a newer technique and used it for rounding purpose. However it turned into nightmare because it started rounding even mentissa part of number.

For example,

`Number = 1.5294` is rounded to `1.5`

`Number = 10.5294` is rounded to `10`

`Number = 101.5294` is rounded to `100`

.... and so on

So this is not the behavior I expected for rounding (as precision = 2).

It seems to be having some logic because from patter I can say that it takes first two digits (as precision is 2) of number and then appends 0's till the no. of digits become same as unrounded amount (checkout the example of 101.5294 ...)

Comment: so can you suggest for instead solution as well?