# Java BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

What is the 3 for in the below code:

To suite your fancy better here is the original question:

```
 public float getOrderTotal(float taxRate) {
        BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal("0.0", 3);
        for (int i = 0; i < orderItems.length(); i++) {
            total.add(String.valueOf(orderItems[i].getCost(taxRate)));
        }
        return total.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP).floatValue();
    }
```

Comment: API Docs is your friend, always try to look there. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(java.lang.String, java.math.MathContext)

Comment: Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539/use-of-java-math-mathcontext

Comment: There is no such constructor, code won't compile, also there is a bug in add() method call, BigDecimal are immutable

Comment: This is obviously homework or maybe even an actual exam and the students have access to Internet for some reason.

Comment: um no neither actually

Comment: the original question is what the 3 is used for, and after there were answers for that, I posted the full example in case anyone wanted to know.  thank you for your obvious, not so obvious answer tho.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid constructor for `BigDecimal`. There is no constructor matched with `String` and `int`.

```
new BigDecimal("0.0", 3); // wrong constructor
```

If you want to find more follow [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Comment: Thanks everyone....  just in case anybody was wondering this is the example I am trying to work on.

Answer (score -1):

The 3 is a scala. Also u should construct as follows

For example, this:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("1234567890.123456789",new MathContext(20)));
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("1234567890.123456789",new MathContext(10))); 
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("1234567890.123456789",new MathContext(5)));
```

will output:

```
1234567890.123456789
1234567890
1.2346E+9
```